# Why rsync fails with jenkins

Tags: ssh, jenkins, centos, rsync, selinux

When rsync is used with jenkins as Execute shell Command on CentOS 6.4, it fails:

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3424899639384884888.sh
+ rsync -av /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myjob/workspace/target/classes/ myuser@myserver.com:/home/myuser/test
rsync: Failed to exec ssh: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(84) [sender=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

However, it works from the command line:

```
su jenkins
rsync -av /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myjob/workspace/target/classes/ myuser@myserver.com:/home/myuser/test
sending incremental file list

sent 17875 bytes  received 83 bytes  3990.67 bytes/sec
total size is 1981027  speedup is 110.31
```

What has to be done to make it work in jenkins as well?

Comment: Do you have the ssh key copied into the remote machine? When you do it from the command line, do you have to type in your username and pasaword?

Comment: The ssh key is on the remote machine, when I do it from the command line I don't have to type my user name and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with SElinux installed on CentOS, which for some reason were blocking ssh for rsync.

Here is a line from /var/log/messages which says the ssh was blocked:

```
Jun 12 13:45:59 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1434109559.911:33346): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=11862 comm="rsync" name="ssh" dev=dm-1 ino=11931741 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:rsync_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ssh_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
```

For now we disabled SElinux on our server, proper solution would be to create custom policy module ([1](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01))

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

In my case jenkins was not executing rsync with the expected user (jenkins) but with another (jboss in my case)
adding '`whoami`' to the script and using ssh verbose:

```
rsync -e "ssh -v" .......
```

helped to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note, that when you change (add) jenkins user to some group, permission will apply after slave (agent) restart.